# Admission webhook creation connection refused error Minikube

Tags: kubernetes, webhooks, minikube

I want to create a webhook on pods creation. Kubernetes is running with minikube that is why for ca_bundle I am using the path to the ca.pem in the minikube/certs folder. However, I get such an error when I apply webhook configuration:

```
error: unable to recognize "pods-webhook.yaml": Get https://minikube-ip:8443/api?timeout=32s: dial tcp minikube-ip:8443: connect: connection refused
```

Is there anything else I should configure and should I set up another file for the ca_bundle?

I want to use this admission hook from the java-client.
Here is the pods-webhook.yaml file:

```
apiVersion: admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ValidatingWebhookConfiguration
metadata:
  name: pods-webhook
webhooks:
  - name: create-pods-webhook
    rules:
      - apiGroups:
          - ""
        apiVersions:
          - v1
        operations:
          - CREATE
        resources:
          - pods
    clientConfig:
      service:
        name: create-pods-webhook-svc
        namespace: default
        path: "/validate"
      caBundle: ${CA_BUNDLE}
```